# How to split console into different "modules/containers"?

Tags: javascript, console

I wanted to create a Twitch chat program for my terminal and wanted to split it between two or more channels, how could I create something like modules? To be able to position and update each one separately from each other? Without opening another terminal instance.
Kind of like how some terminal programs, like Glances separate their sensors and process list.

```
| Channel Name   || Channel Name   |
|----------------||----------------|
| user: message  || user: message  |
```

I've tried googling, although I can't really find anything on this. I am wondering if there is a NPM package that can help with this, or how I could possibly learn to create and then expand on the idea.

Comment: Example library: https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink